# Receiving 401.1 Unauthorized from IIS on server on everything except Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, .net-5

I have set up a REST API in .NET 5 which is deployed on IIS.
The API works perfectly for when deployed on local IIS but when I deploy it to a target server it shows some odd behaviour.

When I call the API with a .NET client application or with Postman I receive a 401.1 response. However if I use the Swagger page everything is completely fine. Can anyone explain why this could be the case?

Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "ITS.Mailing.API v1"));
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

All the topics I've come across so far indicate issues with the order of statements in the Startup.cs but that doesn't seem to be the issue. I'm currently at my wits end, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Only 401? No details? Did you try with postman?

Comment: The only information returned is a basic html error page containing the following message:
https://netwrix.secure.force.com/kb/servlet/rtaImage?eid=ka00g000000HKHd&feoid=00N0g000004CA0p&refid=0EM700000004xce

This is the message I received while using Postman.

Comment: Are you using IIS? Which version?

Comment: I'm using IIS 2016. The issue seems to have magically resolved itself. Before I could only  receive an answer in Postman if I enabled Anonymous Access in IIS but now it's able to get a proper response with only Windows Authentication enabled.